# cocos2dx JNIHelper lib is missing

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to add JNI to my project but I'm getting linker error:

```
 Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
 "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl
 cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(struct cocos2d::JniMethodInfo_&,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (__imp_?getStaticMethodInfo@JniHelper@cocos2d@@SA_NAAUJniMethodInfo_@2@PBD11@Z)referenced in function _callEndGame    AndroidJNI_EndGameDelegate.obj  Proj.win32
```

Inside libcocos2d.lib there is no such a function because cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln project didn't compile cocos2d-x-2.2.4\cocos2dx\platform\android folder.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you building for Anrdoid from Visual Studio?

Comment: This part I'm building using VS, but JNI calls are located in common, non-android part of project. Should I move it to android part? Here is some details http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/jnihelper-lib-is-missing/15618

Comment: Yeah, you should only be using JNI for Android. I don't know why else you'd want to use Java code in your project.

Comment: Can somebody give me working sample project with JNI?

Comment: The cocos2d-x project itself is what I used. In the cocos2d-x folder go to `cocos2dx -> platform -> android` and look at how they do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
It appears because I tried to compile my project from VS.
But when I use native_build.sh compilation was done without errors.